# ILASM problem when dealing with double NaN and Inf

Tags: c#, .net, cil, ilasm

I create a simple program with a double type value initialized,

> var a = double.NaN;

I build the project with Visual Studio 2019, .net framework 4.5
and disassemble it into a .il file using ILDASM.exe Version 4.0.30319.0

> IL_0001:  ldc.r8     -nan(ind)

but there is an error when I try to assemble it using ILASM.exe Version 4.8.3752.0

> test.il(65) : error : syntax error at token '-' in:     IL_0001:  ldc.r8     -nan(ind)

This happened to Double.PositiveInfinity and Double.NegativeInfinity too.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the error reason from [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/545431/ildasmexe-regression-with-infinum-floating-point-v.html)

and the simple solution is just to replace the:

> ldc.r8     -nan(ind) -> ldc.r8     (00 00 00 00 00 00 F8 FF)

> ldc.r8     inf -> ldc.r8     (00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 7F)

> ldc.r8     -inf -> ldc.r8     (00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 FF)

Comment: Someone should tell them, no ?

Comment: Wouldnt have been able to fix this today unless I land on this page. Thanks. I think this is bug from Microsoft should have been taken care by now

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get around this by copying ildasm from an older machine.
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools"

My new machine only had "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools" and i renamed ildasm.exe and added the 4.6 one.